# JAVA import while using regex to solve

Tags: java, import

Why we have to include both java.util.* and java.util.regex.* while working with regex?java.util.regex.* should be in java.util.* if i am right.

Comment: `java.util.regex` is a different package from `java.util`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wildcard imports only work for classes directly in the package, not for subpackages.

If you use

```java
import java.util.*;
```

You will import all classes directly in the package`java.util` (e.g. `Collection`) but not classes in subpackages like `java.util.regex` (e.g. `Pattern`).

If you want to use wildcard imports for both, use two import statements:

```java
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
```

If you just want to import regex classes, you don't necessarily need `java.util`:

```java
import java.util.regex.*;
```

Comment: `import java.util.*` means that you import all classes directly in `java.util` but not in subpackages. Subpackages are more like a logical structure.